# Mosquitto not starting

Tags: mqtt

I posted this on stack overflow however they reccomended I post it here,

I recently installed the Mosquitto MQTT broker on Windows 11, and I managed to get it working locally between different command prompt windows. However, after restarting my laptop Mosquitto will not start from the services tab. If I try to start it from the services menu I get an error saying:

Mosquitto started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs

If I try to start it through the command line with sc mosquitto start it appears to start normally. However, if I try to publish or subscribe to a topic it gives me the error:

no connection could be made as the target machine actively refused it

I had edited the mosquitto.conf file so I tried undoing my edits by replacing my version with an unedited version from GitHub, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: The default config has the same impact as a blank file (all options are commented out) so try emptying the config. It's also worth trying to run it manually (`cd C:\Program Files\mosquitto` then `.\mosquitto.exe -v -c mosquitto.conf`. If that starts without issue, it's worth checking the `MOSQUITTO_DIR` environmental variable (this determines the determines where Mosquitto looks for the config when running as a service).

Comment: @Brits Thanks for that, I tried running running it manually and I got the following error:  1697098990: Error: Empty acl_file value in configuration.
1697098990: Error found at mosquitto.conf:20.

Comment: Check line 20 of the `mosquitto.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Line 20 had nothing in it. I ended up fixing the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling mosquitto. Thanks @brits

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling mosquitto.

Thanks